# MongoMapper getting data from a query

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

I'm trying to return a `User` with MongoMapper:

Here's the user

```
1.9.3-p194 :004 > User.where(:email => 'redacted@gmail.com').all.count
=> 1 

1.9.3-p194 :005 > User.where(:email => 'redacted@gmail.com').first.class
=> User
```

Looks good up to here...

```
1.9.3-p194 :005 > u = User.where(:email => 'redacted@gmail.com').first.class
=> User

1.9.3-p194 :007 > u.email
    NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for User:Class
    from /home/zensavona/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dynamic_querying.rb:39:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):7
    from /home/zensavona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

My understanding is that `u` holds an instance of `User`, but if this is so, why can't I access `u`'s properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the class `User` to the variable `u` instead of the instance of `User` which actually holds the data.

Try this instead:

```ruby
u = User.where(:email => 'redacted@gmail.com').first
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not thinking this afternoon!